Sending RC Channel Data via CRSF Protocol from Raspberry Pi to Drone using ROS
I am working on a project where I want to control a drone using the CRSF protocol by replacing the ELRS RX receiver with a Raspberry Pi. My goal is to send RC channel data, including Throttle, Pitch, Roll, Yaw, and AUX channels, from the Raspberry Pi to the drone under the CRSF protocol.
Does ROS have a standard library or package that supports sending RC channel data via the CRSF protocol?
